# Join returns no results

Tags: t-sql, trigger, sql-server-2017

In a trigger, I have:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.Id
FROM deleted d
INNER JOIN Table t 
ON t.Id = d.Id

SELECT TOP 1 t.Id
FROM Table t
WHERE t.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 d.Id FROM deleted d)
```

Table is a related table that references the trigger's table. Trigger is after Delete

Why does the first return no result but the second does?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS and version.

Comment: Is it a trigger `ON Table FOR DELETE`? And is Id PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @McNets No, Table is a related table that references the trigger's table. Trigger is after Delete.

Comment: What are all the TOP 1s signifying? How are they ordered? How do you know?

Comment: I don’t know how to print a result set.

Comment: It would help if you posted the trigger code and the tables' definitions (CREATE TABLE statements.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship was setting Table's foreign key to null before the trigger was running - so no rows to join to.

I'm not sure why the `IN` query worked. I suspect that when I tested it, the delete action was set to no action and the trigger ultimately failed.

Answer (score 3):

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) has pointed out on his comment, the only reason you has no records could be related to the order. But IMHO first query should return one record unless there are no coincidences on the related table.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T
> (
>     ID INT, 
>     F1 CHAR(1),
>     PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D');
>
> CREATE TABLE TREF
> (
>     ID INT, 
>     F1 CHAR(1),
>     PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO TREF VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(5,'C'),(6,'D');
>
> CREATE TABLE T1
> (
>     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>     RES NVARCHAR(MAX)
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER TRG_T_DELETE
> ON T
> AFTER DELETE
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     INSERT INTO T1
>     SELECT 'COUNT: ' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM deleted;
>
>     INSERT INTO T1
>     SELECT 'deleted: ' + (SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE ID = d.ID FOR XML RAW) 
>     FROM   deleted d;
>
>     INSERT INTO T1
>     SELECT TOP 1
>            'join: ' + (SELECT * FROM TREF WHERE ID = T.ID FOR XML RAW) 
>     FROM   deleted d
>     JOIN   TREF T
>     ON     T.ID = D.ID;
>
>
>     INSERT INTO T1
>     SELECT TOP 1 'IN: ' + (SELECT * FROM TREF WHERE ID = T.ID FOR XML RAW) 
>     FROM   TREF T
>     WHERE  T.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM deleted ORDER BY ID DESC)    
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM T WHERE ID >= 2;
> SELECT * FROM T1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | RES                          
> -: | :----------------------------
>  1 | COUNT: 3                     
>  2 | deleted: <row ID="2" F1="B"/>
>  3 | deleted: <row ID="3" F1="C"/>
>  4 | deleted: <row ID="4" F1="D"/>
>  5 | join: <row ID="2" F1="B"/>
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea95ed471aa5a90adb2a0cf15e0b9123)*